# How to send text data to Thinkspeak channel from Android app?

Tags: android, server, kotlin, httprequest

I am able to send integer value (1234) to thinkspeak channel field1 with below code:

```
val httpclient = OkHttpClient() // create an HTTP client                 
val request = Request.Builder().url("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=YGEQ_MYKEY=1234").build()
httpclient.newCall(request).execute()
```

But I am not able to send text value (SAJAN). How can I send text value to thinkspeak? I have tried below code but it's not working.

```
val httpclient = OkHttpClient() // create an HTTP client             
val request = Request.Builder().url("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=YGEQ_MYKEY=SAJAN").build()
httpclient.newCall(request).execute()
```

Comment: try name in single quotes.      val request = Request.Builder().url("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=YGEQQIJV5NAKLURL&field1='SAJAN' ").build()
httpclient.newCall(request).execute()

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Show your Log for int value and string.

Comment: do you know where can i see request text in thinkspeak channel

Comment: While i'm trying your link with single quotes, i returned a count 29, when i refresh it incremented to 30. Checked in browser. If it is your private key, please remove it from question.

Comment: Looks like api storing the content and returning id or count something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the "&field1=SAJAN" parameter on the URL.

```
val httpclient = OkHttpClient() // create an HTTP client             
val request = Request.Builder().url("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=YGEQ_MYKEY&field1=SAJAN").build()
httpclient.newCall(request).execute()
```

To see that this string has been sent, you will have to read the string back using the ThingSpeak API. The charts will only display numeric values.